# Java Map Grouping

Tags: java, hashmap

i have a following map with values, I want to group map values according to sum part of key like;

```
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160712-20160713 T0",0.8584570960451277);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160714-20160715 T0",0.500990414391463);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160716-20160717 T1",0.5020244439749132);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160718-20160719 T1",0.43098357500551543);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160720-20160721 T4",0.5153793685149496);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160722-20160723 T3",0.4623046631067317);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160724-20160725 T0",0.4512717518558771);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160726-20160727 T4",0.36536108872340967);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160728-20160729 T1",0.3912641598156222);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T0_20160730-20160731 T4",0.28587189421297915);

map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160712-20160713 T1",0.8580146171263094);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160714-20160715 T1",0.9332823713689552);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160716-20160717 T0",0.71982167666725);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160718-20160719 T2",0.8699615471928571);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160720-20160721 T2",0.9278777878143865);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160722-20160723 T2",0.9344990001901656);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160724-20160725 T3",0.9400899408159816);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160726-20160727 T0",0.8886183195622867);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160728-20160729 T2",0.8298196046334939);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T1_20160730-20160731 T1",0.8409421997212592);

map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160712-20160713 T3",0.6215375875768216);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160714-20160715 T2",0.6464517487397089);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160716-20160717 T0",0.18854087266412126);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160718-20160719 T0",0.7104484324839435);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160720-20160721 T2",0.2253283933151363);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160722-20160723 T4",0.6041580606290883);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160724-20160725 T2",0.41264702138230575);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160726-20160727 T1",0.34820930964241165);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160728-20160729 T4",0.6120977235710975);
map.put("20160710-20160711 T2_20160730-20160731 T1",0.12926293940300582);
```

First i want to create a folder named by for each unique keys.substring(0,17)
then i want to create a data.csv file in this folder which contains keys.substring(21,38) and its values.

As an example  suppose we are in a loop;

for i =0;

I will create a folder which name is 20160710-20160711 T0 then in this folder i will create data.csv file. Then to each single line i will write following to that file;

20160712-20160713 T0 , 0.8584570960451277
20160714-20160715 T0 , 0.500990414391463
20160716-20160717 T1 , 0.5020244439749132
20160718-20160719 T1 , 0.43098357500551543
20160720-20160721 T4 , 0.5153793685149496
20160722-20160723 T3 , 0.4623046631067317
20160724-20160725 T0 , 0.4512717518558771
20160726-20160727 T4 , 0.36536108872340967
20160728-20160729 T1 , 0.3912641598156222
20160730-20160731 T4 , 0.28587189421297915

for i =1 i will create folder which name is 20160710-20160711 T1 then i will create a data.csv in it and write following values in it;

20160712-20160713 T1",0.8580146171263094
20160714-20160715 T1",0.9332823713689552
20160716-20160717 T0",0.71982167666725
20160718-20160719 T2",0.8699615471928571
20160720-20160721 T2",0.9278777878143865
20160722-20160723 T2",0.9344990001901656
20160724-20160725 T3",0.9400899408159816
20160726-20160727 T0",0.8886183195622867
20160728-20160729 T2",0.8298196046334939
20160730-20160731 T1",0.8409421997212592

and so on. 
It should continue like this.. My question is how can i parse and group key in a java map, (just grouping map is enough for me creation of files and writing is not matter.) 
Thank you very much for your interest and sincerity with best regards..

Comment: What is your question? Since you didn't ask any question, I'm guessing that you're looking for people to write your code for you?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i m not looking for people to write my code, my question is how can i parse and group key in a java map. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is:

```
Map<String, List<Entry<String, String>>> result = 
  map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e->e.getKey().substring(0,17)));
```

This will turn the map into a stream, and then convert it into a map going from the string to a list of entries. You could also filter or map the entries if you wish by adding more calls into the stream before the collect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet of what I used to do to group by over a Map
hope this is good for you to start

```
   Map<String, Map<String, Double>> output = new HashMap<>();
   for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        Map m = output.get(key.substring(0, 17));
        if (!output.containsKey(key.substring(0, 17)))
            m = new HashMap<>();
        output.get(key.substring(0, 17)).put(key.substring(17, 21), map.get(key))
   }
```

Comment: It would be better to use Streams to do this really with Java 8 :)

Comment: See the answer I just added.